# Symfony3: persist and flush the valid part of a collection on form submit with errors

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have the following entities and abstract types below.

Since my mission has a many-to-many relation with a entity that contains a file, when one of the file have an Assert that fails, the form cannot repopulate the selected file and I don't know how to handle the errors then.

Would there be a way to persist the part of the collection of PieceJointe that is valid and then let the user edit the invalid entries only, before she sends the form again?

**UPDATE**: maybe something like that? Although I tried that, but the persisted `PieceJointe` is not linked to the `Mission`.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
         $em->persist($etapeMission);
         $em->flush();
    } else {
        foreach ($form->get('mission')->get('pieces_jointes') as $pj) {
            if ($pj->isValid()) {
                $em->persist($pj);
                $em->flush($pj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Important point**:

- the `Mission` entity which the collection is attached to already exists when the form is submitted the first time
- the `EtapeMission` entity is not really relevant here since it doesn't have a role in the relation. Although, I put it here cause that is the entity of the form I am submitting (I upload files for a `Mission` from an `EtapeMission` form that belongs the the so called `Mission`

Thank you for your help. Any advice, idea, etc. is welcome.

Mission.php:

```
class Mission
{
// ...

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\EtapeMission
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\EtapeMission", inversedBy="missionAsPreCadrage")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pre_cadrage_etape_mission_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $preCadrageEtapeMission;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\EtapeMission
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\EtapeMission", inversedBy="missionAsCadrage")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cadrage_etape_mission_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $cadrageEtapeMission;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\EtapeMission
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\EtapeMission", inversedBy="missionAsValidation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="validation_etape_mission_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $validationEtapeMission;

/**
 * @var Collection<PieceJointe>
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\PieceJointe", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="missions_pieces_jointes",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="mission_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="piece_jointe_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *     )
 */
private $piecesJointes;

// ...
}
```

EtapeMission.php:

```
class EtapeMission
{
// ...

/**
 * @var Mission
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Mission", mappedBy="preCadrageEtapeMission", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $missionAsPreCadrage;

/**
 * @var Mission
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Mission", mappedBy="cadrageEtapeMission", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $missionAsCadrage;

/**
 * @var Mission
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Mission", mappedBy="validationEtapeMission", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $missionAsValidation;

// ...
}
```

PieceJointe.php

```
class PieceJointe
{
// ...

/**
 * @var UploadedFile
 *
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "4096k"
 * )
 */
private $file;

/**
 * @var Collection<Mission>
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Mission", mappedBy="piecesJointes")
 */
private $missions;

// ...
}
```

Here is my abstract types:

EtapeMissionType.php:

```
class EtapeMissionType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // ...
        ->add('mission', PiecesJointesCollectionType::class);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => EtapeMission::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

PiecesJointesCollectionType.php:

```
class PiecesJointesCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('pieces_jointes', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => PieceJointeType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new Valid(),
            ],
        ]);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Mission::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

PieceJointeType:

```
class PieceJointeType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file', FileType::class, [
            'label' => false,
        ]);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => PieceJointe::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when one of the file fails the assertion" ?

Comment: If for example, here I have an assert on the UploadedFile which check the file size, so if this fails. And my issue is that then the invalid form will display again with the errors but since it is a input of type file, it won't be populated with the file the user chose before submitting. So since I have a collection of files, the ones that pass the assert won't be able to upload correctly after the form is submitted again. So I am looking for a way to still persist the valid entities of PieceJointe even though the form is not completely valid. Hope tis makes sense (update my original post)

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense. Your update helps, and your proposed solution feels right. To solve your problem of `PieceJointe` not linked to `Mission`, you could just manually set that before persisting (something like `$mission = $form->get('mission'); $pj->addMission($mission); $em->persist($pj);`).

Comment: Ok I will try that thank you. I am a bit skeptical though about manually having to do this. Also with having to flush the PieceJointe individually so Doctrine doesn't flush the entities that are not valid. Won't there be a Doctrine feature to help me with that?

Comment: I think the only caveat will be that your PieceJointe entity is on the inverse side of the ManyToMany relationship, so somewhere in your code you will have to update the owning side (`Mission`) with something like `$mission->addPiecesJointes($pj);`. Adjust as needed of course.

Comment: Although, since the `Mission` entity is mapped thanks to the form with the `PieceJointe` Collection, the `PieceJointe` I will be adding cause valid will already be in the `Mission` collection of `PieceJointe`.

Comment: So I simply ended up removing the invalid entities from the collection and then flush the whole, and it works. I then add back the invalid entities before rendering the form again so the failing ones show. Although now if I submit the form again without fixing the errors, the files are empty and adding a not null assert makes all the entities of the collection fail (cause the file attribute is only populated on creation). Is there a way to loop through only the invalid entities or make an assert active on new entities only?

Comment: I was able to fix that last problem by adding a custom validation rule in the entity as a callback, so it check that the files is not null if the id is (so it checks only new entities). Although now, when I resend the form, the entity that I flushed just before as still seen as new element of the collection from the form and get erased on the next submit. Is there a way, after I flush the valid entities, to tell the form to refresh its data so it takes into account that these entities are not new anymore? Thank you !